# Change the Windows 8 lock screen background?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I would like to change the Windows 8 Lock Screen background image via c# code.

I am very familiar with how to do this in Windows 7, and also that Windows 8 doesn't support this method.

I tried using Process Monitor while changing it over and over again through SystemSettings.exe but nothing stood out to me.

This seems to be the only discussion that's gotten anywhere: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/a8db890c-204f-404a-bf74-3aa4c895b183

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look to - [Lock screen personalization sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personalization-App-sample-9ebfe147) (How to use `LockScreen API` to set the current user's lock screen image). Maybe would be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks!  My Google'ing skills must be getting rusty.

Comment: No problem. I see you in the next Google Search summer camp xD