# Change Lockscreen from desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1, lockscreen

I want to change Windows 8.1 lockscreen and user picture from C# desktop application.
I know its very easy to do it in Windows Store Apps.

But I didn't know how to access Lockscreen class in normal desktop app.

How can I access those classes from WPF application. Is there any other way to chnage lockscreen and user picture I am missing.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this question [Change the Windows 8 lock screen background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105690/change-the-windows-8-lock-screen-background)